# Data Preprocessing and resampling using tidymodels

Tags: r, tidyverse, metrics, roc, auc

I was following this Youtube video from Julia Silge and I could not finish the exercise.
In this part of the code the following error appear:

```
set.seed(234)
glm_rs <- glm_spec %>%
  fit_resamples(diversity ~ .,
                folds,
                metrics = metric_set(roc_auc,sens,spec),
                control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE))


Error: 
The combination of metric functions must be:
- only numeric metrics
- a mix of class metrics and class probability metrics

The following metric function types are being mixed:
- prob (roc_auc)
- class (sens)
- other (spec <namespace:readr>)
```

Any idea, what's going on ?

Regards

Lucas Zago

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem. I used `tidymodels::tidymodels_prefer` and found that it has no effect.

The final solution was to update tidymodels:

```r
    packages(install.packages("tidymodels"))
```

Or you can try `yardstick::spec`.